# Is it possible to assign an variable to return result?

Tags: python, data-science

Is it possible to assign a variable to an return result of an function ?

First I want to acquire the website from email like for e.g xxxxx@hotmail.com will return only hotmail.com. Then if that website is equal to 'hotmail.com' return 'Yes' if not equal return 'No'.

```
def mail(var):

x = return var.split('@')[1]

if x == 'hotmail.com':
    return 'Yes'
else:
    return 'No'
```

I know it's not the right code but I hope You get the idea. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Your code looks like it's formatted incorrectly, but what you're doing isn't correct - once you do `return`, it stops the current method's execution.

Comment: No, it is not possible. You can store the value in a variable and return two variables separating them by comma like `return 'yes', x`. It would return a tuple that you can descompress with two variables on the left side of an asignation.

Comment: You should remove the `return` in `x` assignment and just do `x = var.split('@')[1]`. After that, the behavior you expect should be there.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is this:

```
def mail(var):
  return 'Yes' if var.split('@')[1] == 'hotmail.com' else 'No'

x = mail('foo@hotmail.com')

print(x)
```

**Note:**

If *var* does not contain '@' this will fail with IndexError

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove your first return, beacause then your function immediately exits, then it works:

```
def mail(var):
    x = var.split('@')[1]
    if x == 'hotmail.com':
        return 'Yes'
    else:
        return 'No'

print(mail('user@hotmail.com'))
print(mail('user@gmail.com'))
```

Output:

```
Yes
No
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to validate the email in parameter to avoid exception by checking if it contains `'@'` in argument and checking for dot (`'.'`) within index of `'@'` to the last char, if it's invalid then return `'is not valid email'`. If it's a valid email then assign the value of variable `x` by indicing from next index of `'@'` (same result as split). And the last, check if `x` is fit to the condition that you want (in this example: `'hotmail.com'`)

```
def mail(var):
    if '@' in var and '.' in var[var.index('@'):]:
        x = var[var.index('@')+1:]
        print(x)
        return 'Yes' if x == 'hotmail.com' else 'No'
    else:
        return f'{var} is not valid email'


print(mail('xxxxx@gmailjp'))
print(mail('xxxxxgmail.com'))
print(mail('xxxxxgmailnl'))
print(mail('xxxxx@gmail.us'))
print(mail('xxxxx@hotmail.com'))

# xxxxx@gmailjp is not valid email
# xxxxxgmail.com is not valid email
# xxxxxgmailnl is not valid email
# gmail.us
# No
# hotmail.com
# Yes
```

But I prefer this:

```
def mail(var):
    return 'Yes' if 'hotmail.com' in var else 'No'

print(mail('xxxxx@gmail.us'))
print(mail('xxxxx@hotmail.com'))

# No
# Yes
```